# Drupal: add a js function callback to Drupal.settings

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal, fancybox

Im using `[drupal_add_js_()][1]` function to add a [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) effect to some image in my nodes (im not using the Fancybox module becose doesnt fit my needs).

In short, i need to add the `titleFormat` function to format the image title; In my javascript file, it looks like:

```
$("a[rel=myfancy_group]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'titlePosition': 'over',
    'titleFormat': function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
        return '<span><b>' + title + '</b> | Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' of ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
    }
});
```

And this is how my `drupal_add_js` function looks:

```
drupal_add_js(
    array(
        'mycustom_fancybox' => array(
            'selector' => 'div.field-field-immagini-minigallery a',
            'group' => TRUE,
            'options' => array(
                'transitionIn' => 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' => 'elastic',
                'titlePosition' => 'inside',
                'titleShow' => TRUE,
                'width' => 500,
                'cyclic' => TRUE,
                'titleFormat' => ???
            )
        )
    ),
    'setting',
    'footer',
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    TRUE
);
```

**EDIT** i've tryed with:

```
//add fancybox settings
drupal_add_js(
    array(
        'mycustom_fancybox' => array(
            'selector' => 'div.field-field-immagini-minigallery a',
            'group' => TRUE,
            'options' => array(
                'transitionIn' => 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' => 'elastic',
                'titlePosition' => 'inside',
                'titleShow' => TRUE,
                'width' => 500,
                'cyclic' => TRUE,
                'titleFormat' => "function my_title_format(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) { return '<span><b><i>' + title + '</i></b> | Immagine ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' di ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>'; }"
            )
        )
    ),
    'setting',
    'footer',
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    TRUE
);
```

but (as i supposed) Drupal render it like:

```
"function (title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) { return \'\x3cspan\x3e\x3cb\x3e\x3ci\x3e\' + title + \'\x3c/i\x3e\x3c/b\x3e | Immagine \' + (currentIndex + 1) + \' di \' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? \' \x26nbsp; \' + title : \'\') + \'\x3c/span\x3e\'; }"
```

...and it doesnt work.

I tryed

```
drupal_add_js(
    array(
        'mycustom_fancybox' => array(
            'selector' => 'div.field-field-immagini-minigallery a',
            'group' => TRUE,
            'options' => array(
                'transitionIn' => 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' => 'elastic',
                'titlePosition' => 'inside',
                'titleShow' => TRUE,
                'width' => 500,
                'cyclic' => TRUE,
                'titleFormat' => 'my_title_format'
            )
        )
    ),
    'setting',
    'footer',
    FALSE,
    TRUE,
    TRUE
);
//and, in my js file, added:
function my_title_format(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
    return '<span><b><i>' + title + '</i></b> | Immagine ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' di ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
}
```

But again doestn work.

Comment: The overall objective of the question is not clear to me. You want to add `titleFormat` and you're not able to get it to work?

Comment: @NoParrots: i want to add the titleFormat options in Drupal.settings, but i dont know how to do it becose titleFormat is not a string/boolean value, burt a function callback.

Comment: Have you tried just passing the function callback in the options array? does it work? If not, what about enclosing the function definition within single quotes?

Comment: Why you need to add it in Drupal.settings? That's not a place to put javascript code, only settings. Can't you make it work, adding the first piece of code you have as 'inline' for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look for js Drupal.theme mechanizm. 
Example I took from module/block/block.js

```
    // A custom message for the blocks page specifically.
  Drupal.theme.tableDragChangedWarning = function () {
    return '<div class="warning">' + Drupal.theme('tableDragChangedMarker') + ' ' + Drupal.t("The changes to these blocks will not be saved until the <em>Save blocks</em> button is clicked.") + '</div>';
  };
```

It can be usefull. But it realy looks you need just separated js file that will get Drupal.settings you need and insert them to code applied fancy.

Answer (score 0):

On second thoughts ... why do you need to send the function callback *definition*? The purpose of drupal_add_js is to pass parameters. The function callback is never changing, right? You can always define it in your custom javascript file...

Comment: You're right, will be much better, i've tryed to pass just the name function in drupal_add_js, but it doesnt work (i've update my question)